# React : how to load image outside src and public folders

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, create-react-app, src

My project as this kind of structure :

```
├── api
├── db
│   └── images
├── ui
│   └── public
│   └── src
│   |    └── App.js
```

My app was created using create-react-app so I can't import files outside of src directory, and I do not want these images to be in  the public folder : how can I have an `img` tag :

`<img src="db/images/img_1.jpg">`

with src getting images on db/images folder, completely outside of react app ?

Thank you for your replies

Comment: I don't think react can get items from outside of your root folder `ui` in your case. I remember seeing errors, but I may also be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to put the image inside of your `src` and reference it in a react fashion. Consider the following:

```
├── ui
│   └── public
│   └── src
│   |    └── App.js
         └── img_1.jpg
```

app.js

`import img from "./img_1.jpg";`

then in your render `img` tag

`<img src={img} />`

Hoping this might work for you? iirc this will prevent someone from hotloading the image from your public folder.

If there's literally 0 way of moving the images into your react project, the only way I can think is to upload the images somewhere and reference them from a literal link, such as S3

Comment: I tried this solution but since you can upload files from react in my app, my dev server reload each times I upload something (since src folder is updated). That's why I want them to be completely split from react app

Comment: Why do you want to prevent hot reloading?

Comment: I want the app to reload when I update the code and save, but when I upload image from react app and store them in src folder, the app reload automatically and that's disturbing

Answer (score 0):

If you just don't want it to reload when you upload a file, you can ignore the folder the files are uploaded to in you webpack config

```
devServer: {
    ...
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: './src/images/**/.*',
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The create-react-app package uses a plugin for Webpack called `ModuleScopePlugin` that causes this behavior

You can use the package [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) for override the webpack configs.

The customize-cra has a method to resolve your problem.

[removeModuleScopePlugin](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra/blob/master/api.md#removemodulescopeplugin)

or you can eject from create-react-app and remove this config manually at webpack